# Android: Media Player Cannot prepare when streaming mp3 from url

Tags: android, url, crash, media-player

After hours of searching through the web I ,still, can't find a way to stream mp3 files in android.
Here is my simple java code:

```
package com.khagendra.livestreamaudio;

import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;


public class BlurPlayer extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button buttonStop,buttonStart ;

    String AudioURL = "http://www.android-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Thunder-rumble.mp3";

    MediaPlayer mediaplayer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_blur_player);

        buttonStart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        buttonStop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

        mediaplayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaplayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

        buttonStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"start",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                try {

                    mediaplayer.setDataSource(AudioURL);
                    mediaplayer.prepare();


                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SecurityException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                 mediaplayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                     @Override
                     public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"prepared",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                         mediaplayer.start();
                     }
                 });

            }
        });

        buttonStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"stop",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mediaplayer.stop();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I have added the permission in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

I only have two buttons in layout with id button1 and button2.
At first I was using `mediaplayer.prepare();` and the logcat output was

```
06-26 12:03:57.680    3249-3249/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
06-26 12:03:57.680    3249-3249/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
06-26 12:03:57.680    3249-3249/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve interface method 15147: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
06-26 12:03:57.680    3249-3249/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
06-26 12:03:57.680    3249-3249/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
06-26 12:03:57.680    3249-3249/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve interface method 15151: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
06-26 12:03:57.680    3249-3249/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
06-26 12:03:57.760    3249-3249/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
06-26 12:03:57.760    3249-3249/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 424: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
06-26 12:03:57.760    3249-3249/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
06-26 12:03:57.760    3249-3249/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
06-26 12:03:57.760    3249-3249/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 446: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
06-26 12:03:57.760    3249-3249/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
06-26 12:03:57.821    3249-3249/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable
06-26 12:03:57.821    3249-3249/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 387: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawable (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
06-26 12:03:57.821    3249-3249/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
06-26 12:03:57.821    3249-3249/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawableForDensity
06-26 12:03:57.821    3249-3249/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 389: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawableForDensity (IILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
06-26 12:03:57.821    3249-3249/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
06-26 12:03:57.831    3249-3249/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio V/MediaPlayer-JNI﹕ native_setup
06-26 12:03:57.831    3249-3249/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio V/MediaPlayer﹕ constructor
06-26 12:03:57.841    3249-3249/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio V/MediaPlayer﹕ setListener
06-26 12:03:57.841    3249-3249/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio V/MediaPlayer-JNI﹕ setAudioStreamType: 3
06-26 12:03:57.841    3249-3249/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio V/MediaPlayer﹕ MediaPlayer::setAudioStreamType
06-26 12:03:57.941    3249-3249/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio D/libEGL﹕ loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLES_vc4.so
06-26 12:03:57.941    3249-3249/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio D/﹕ GPU monitor inactive - could not find libgpumonitor.so [Symbol not found: ] or not enabled (debug.egl.hw.gpumonitor = 0)
06-26 12:03:57.941    3249-3249/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio W/khrn_client﹕ init_window num_buffers 3 min undequeued buffers 1
06-26 12:03:57.941    3249-3249/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio W/khrn_client﹕ init_window window 0x4f50c158, 480x800 hintTransform 0x0 do_pre 1
06-26 12:03:57.961    3249-3249/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
06-26 12:04:03.626    3249-3249/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio V/MediaPlayer﹕ setVideoSurfaceTexture
06-26 12:04:03.626    3249-3249/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio V/MediaPlayer﹕ prepare
06-26 12:04:03.696    3249-3260/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio V/MediaPlayer﹕ message received msg=100, ext1=1, ext2=-1004
06-26 12:04:03.696    3249-3260/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (1, -1004)
06-26 12:04:03.696    3249-3260/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio V/MediaPlayer﹕ signal application thread
06-26 12:04:03.696    3249-3249/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio V/MediaPlayer﹕ prepare complete - status=1
06-26 12:04:03.706    3249-3249/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio W/System.err﹕ java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
06-26 12:04:03.716    3249-3249/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio W/System.err﹕ at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)
06-26 12:04:03.716    3249-3249/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio W/System.err﹕ at com.khagendra.livestreamaudio.BlurPlayer$1.onClick(BlurPlayer.java:44)
06-26 12:04:03.716    3249-3249/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4432)
06-26 12:04:03.716    3249-3249/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18338)
06-26 12:04:03.716    3249-3249/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
06-26 12:04:03.726    3249-3249/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-26 12:04:03.726    3249-3249/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-26 12:04:03.726    3249-3249/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5283)
06-26 12:04:03.726    3249-3249/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-26 12:04:03.726    3249-3249/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-26 12:04:03.726    3249-3249/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
06-26 12:04:03.726    3249-3249/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
06-26 12:04:03.726    3249-3249/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-26 12:04:03.736    3249-3249/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio W/Choreographer﹕ Already have a pending vsync event.  There should only be one at a time.
06-26 12:04:03.746    3249-3249/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio V/MediaPlayer﹕ setVideoSurfaceTexture
06-26 12:04:03.746    3249-3249/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio V/MediaPlayer﹕ prepare
06-26 12:04:03.856    3249-3261/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio V/MediaPlayer﹕ message received msg=100, ext1=1, ext2=-1004
06-26 12:04:03.856    3249-3261/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (1, -1004)
06-26 12:04:03.856    3249-3261/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio V/MediaPlayer﹕ signal application thread
06-26 12:04:03.856    3249-3249/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio V/MediaPlayer﹕ prepare complete - status=1
06-26 12:04:03.856    3249-3249/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio W/System.err﹕ java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
06-26 12:04:03.856    3249-3249/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio W/System.err﹕ at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)
06-26 12:04:03.856    3249-3249/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio W/System.err﹕ at com.khagendra.livestreamaudio.BlurPlayer$1.onClick(BlurPlayer.java:44)
06-26 12:04:03.856    3249-3249/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4432)
06-26 12:04:03.856    3249-3249/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18338)
06-26 12:04:03.856    3249-3249/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
06-26 12:04:03.856    3249-3249/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-26 12:04:03.856    3249-3249/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-26 12:04:03.856    3249-3249/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5283)
06-26 12:04:03.856    3249-3249/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-26 12:04:03.866    3249-3249/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-26 12:04:03.866    3249-3249/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
06-26 12:04:03.866    3249-3249/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
06-26 12:04:03.866    3249-3249/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-26 12:04:03.906    3249-3249/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio I/brcm-gr﹕ [gralloc_lock]: new usage 0x933
06-26 12:04:05.628    3249-3249/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio I/brcm-gr﹕ [gralloc_lock]: new usage 0x933
```

but then I read about `mediaplayer.prepareAsync();`  but of no use. The logcat output this time was:

```
06-26 12:04:52.634    3249-3249/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio W/egl_server﹕ Allocating storage 1x1 surface type 0x1
06-26 12:05:13.785    3645-3645/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
06-26 12:05:13.785    3645-3645/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
06-26 12:05:13.785    3645-3645/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve interface method 15147: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
06-26 12:05:13.785    3645-3645/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
06-26 12:05:13.785    3645-3645/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
06-26 12:05:13.785    3645-3645/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve interface method 15151: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
06-26 12:05:13.785    3645-3645/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
06-26 12:05:14.455    3645-3645/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
06-26 12:05:14.455    3645-3645/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 424: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
06-26 12:05:14.455    3645-3645/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
06-26 12:05:14.465    3645-3645/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
06-26 12:05:14.465    3645-3645/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 446: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
06-26 12:05:14.465    3645-3645/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
06-26 12:05:15.056    3645-3645/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable
06-26 12:05:15.056    3645-3645/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 387: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawable (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
06-26 12:05:15.056    3645-3645/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
06-26 12:05:15.056    3645-3645/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawableForDensity
06-26 12:05:15.056    3645-3645/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 389: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawableForDensity (IILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
06-26 12:05:15.056    3645-3645/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
06-26 12:05:15.086    3645-3645/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio V/MediaPlayer-JNI﹕ native_setup
06-26 12:05:15.086    3645-3645/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio V/MediaPlayer﹕ constructor
06-26 12:05:15.086    3645-3645/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio V/MediaPlayer﹕ setListener
06-26 12:05:15.086    3645-3645/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio V/MediaPlayer-JNI﹕ setAudioStreamType: 3
06-26 12:05:15.086    3645-3645/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio V/MediaPlayer﹕ MediaPlayer::setAudioStreamType
06-26 12:05:15.536    3645-3645/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio D/libEGL﹕ loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLES_vc4.so
06-26 12:05:15.546    3645-3645/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio D/﹕ GPU monitor inactive - could not find libgpumonitor.so [Symbol not found: ] or not enabled (debug.egl.hw.gpumonitor = 0)
06-26 12:05:15.546    3645-3645/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio W/khrn_client﹕ init_window num_buffers 3 min undequeued buffers 1
06-26 12:05:15.546    3645-3645/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio W/khrn_client﹕ init_window window 0x4f50c158, 480x800 hintTransform 0x0 do_pre 1
06-26 12:05:15.576    3645-3645/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
06-26 12:05:20.892    3645-3645/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio V/MediaPlayer﹕ setVideoSurfaceTexture
06-26 12:05:20.892    3645-3645/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio V/MediaPlayer﹕ prepareAsync
06-26 12:05:20.982    3645-3657/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio V/MediaPlayer﹕ message received msg=100, ext1=1, ext2=-1004
06-26 12:05:20.982    3645-3657/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (1, -1004)
06-26 12:05:20.982    3645-3657/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio V/MediaPlayer﹕ callback application
06-26 12:05:20.982    3645-3657/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio V/MediaPlayer﹕ back from callback
06-26 12:05:21.482    3645-3645/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (1,-1004)
06-26 12:05:21.502    3645-3645/com.khagendra.livestreamaudio I/brcm-gr﹕ [gralloc_lock]: new usage 0x933
```

1. I have tested this code on different android phones.(Samsung and Xiaomi)
2. The link:  [The mp3 url](http://www.android-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Thunder-rumble.mp3) is working.
3. **When I test this code for a mp3 file in my sdcard (with permissions) then this code works fine.**
4. I have also tried `MediaPlayer mediaplayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse(AudioURL));`
5. I have also tried changing the link to [another link](https://uksongs.s3.amazonaws.com/18/song_402_2022193270_hita-didiyon.mp3)

I have lost all hope of making this code run fine. *Any help will be highly appreciated.*  Thank you.

Comment: Your problem here is that you used prepare() instead of prepareAsync()

Comment: I have provided two logcat for both prepare() and prepareAsync(). Both cases give error.

Comment: Oh, I see nevermind!

Answer (score 0):

I use this my media player class and its works.

```
        `
public class MediaService extends Service implements  MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener

         //init mediaplayer
         private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

         // and later in the class
         public void playSong(String songPath){
             mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), Uri.parse(songPath)); 
             mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
         }

         public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer player){
            mMediaPlayer.start();
         }`
```

where `songPath` is the song uri from the local device memory or internet url. It's works for the two cases. 
Also try the url in some browser to check that actually works and play audio.

Comment: Thanks for replying. i used your code and it works fine for the mp3 files from my local device memory but when i put a 'Uri.parse(url)' it gives the following error.  `Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side`  `error (1, -1004)`  `java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1` . Any idea what to do next ?

Comment: I tried your provided link 
`String AudioURL = "http://www.android-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Thunder-rumble.mp3";` in my mediaplayer code and its works. Try with another link, just to check is it even works.